# Perl6 NativeCall with Str is encoded('utf16') got randomly corrupted result

Tags: utf-16, raku, nativecall

I am mapping the `GetFullPathName` windows API in a perl6 script using `NativeCall`, for so I wrote the following:

```
#!perl6
use NativeCall;
constant \WIN32_MAX_PATH = 260;    

#I may use directly $path.IO.absolute()
sub Win32-GetFullPathName(
        Str $lpFileName is encoded('utf16'),
        int32 $nBufferLength, 
        #Str $lpBuffer is encoded('utf16') is rw,
        Blob $lpBuffer is rw,
        Str $lpFilenameIndex is rw)
    returns int32
    is native('kernel32.dll') 
    is symbol('GetFullPathNameW') 
    { * }


my $path = '.';
my $fp-size = Win32-GetFullPathName(
        $path, # $path ~ "\0", # <!-- this hack make it working fine
        WIN32_MAX_PATH, 
        #my Str $fpath = ' ' x WIN32_MAX_PATH;
        my $buffer = buf16.allocate(WIN32_MAX_PATH), 
        Str );
put "[$fp-size] => ", $buffer.decode('utf16').substr(0, $fp-size);
```

The code is working randomly, until I append a `"\0"` after `$path`.

[EDIT] The results when called multiple times:

> [12] => D:\dev\pa.t
>
> [12] => D:\dev\pa.
>
> [12] => D:\dev\pa.µºƒ
>
> [9] => D:\dev\pa
>
> [9] => D:\dev\pa

Is there another proper way to do it?

Comment: I think that it may be appending an 8bit null, which is fine for utf8; the problem is this is utf16. I think it is a bug in NativeCall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect a MoarVM bug in `src/strings/utf16.c`, in particular [line 403](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/c9f486317072d29416721e1187e337aff0927826/src/strings/utf16.c#L403):

```
result = MVM_realloc(result, *output_size);
```

which should probably read

```
result = MVM_realloc(result, *output_size + 2);
```

If you could verify that this fixes your problem, feel free to [file a bug report](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/issues) or even [create a pull request](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/edit/master/src/strings/utf16.c).

Comment: Thanks, seams to be that. I'll try it asap.